# Fullcalendar occupancy slot backgound color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I use Fullcalendar in my react application. I need change background color of slot in month timeline resource view if the capacity of day is full or if in this day is some booking. The full day should be red and half capacity orange. Can you take me some solution?

Comment: You can use Background Events for this kind of thing - more info in the documentation

Comment: I think that dayCellClassNames should be better way. But i dont know how it works

Comment: Why do you think it's better? With the background events you can just provide a JSON feed from your server showing the time slots which are occupied...that's what Events are for. The only difference to regular events is that a background event highlights the whole slot rather than just showing an overlay on one part of it.

Comment: Ok. I think it should be little bit faster. And can you help me how to analyze my server data like that?

Comment: Well I don't know anything about your server data or how you store it, or precisely what results you want. That sounds like it might be a SQL / server-side code question if you're stuck, which you can post separately on here. I, and others with relevant experience, might be able to help if you post sufficient details.